# Is it possible to use the MD-Toggle-Button on something else than a button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the material design button toggle (available at this link : https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview) on something else than a simple button. The thing is that even when I try to use with the basic examples of the material documentation, I have this error showing up: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

I already tried all the examples in the Material Design but I still have this error when I call the value with `{{ group.value }}`.

This is my HTML :

```
<section class="content-bonif-wrapper">
<h2> {{ title }} </h2>
<div class="row" class="col-md-4">
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="totalEnc > 0" class="accordion-bonif">
    <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
      <mat-button-toggle value="test" aria-label="Text align justify">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            <span>Risque PR Infiniti</span>
          </mat-panel-title>
          <mat-panel-description >
            <span>Total : {{ totalEnc | number:'1.2-2' }}</span>
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <div>
      <div>
        <a>Encours à charge : {{ totalEncCharge }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<div class="right-content">
  <div>
    {{ group.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I imported the MatButtonToggleModule in my component.ts and in my module.

So my questions are: 
1 - why the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` is showing up? 
2 - can I use the button toggle on something else than a button?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you trying to print template variable?

Comment: After this I would like to call a component with the <app-myComp> but for the moment I am just trying to understand the process of the button toggle group!

Comment: can you please provide link which you are referring ?

Comment: Yep sorry just edited with the link

Comment: where exactly you want to show toggle button, in accordion header or body ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show toggle button inside accordion check this code.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
      <mat-button-toggle value="left" aria-label="Text align left">
        <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="center" aria-label="Text align center">
        <mat-icon>format_align_center</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="right" aria-label="Text align right">
        <mat-icon>format_align_right</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="justify" disabled aria-label="Text align justify">
        <mat-icon>format_align_justify</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <div class="example-selected-value">Selected value: {{group.value}}</div>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

and it's output will be like this.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! But do you know why I still have this error message when I try to use it `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`  and the `{{ group.value }}` don't work?

Comment: group must be null in anytime of your application. use "safe operator" to avoid this {{group?.value}}